# Where are the field formatter settings?

Tags: 8, views, media

When I'm managing a display for an entity and select a field formatter, some formatters have options available (see screenshot 1).

However, when I use that same field formatter in Views, there's no way to set my options.  How can I set my options?

[image]
This works.

[image]
This doesn't have a way to select options.

Comment: Normally the settings are loaded automatically via ajax when you select a formatter. There is no cog.

Answer (score 0):

4k4's comment was helpful in that it indicated the correct behavior.  This isn't what was happening; the POST requests were returning correctly, but I assume they're not returning a correct part of the dialog to replace.

However, with this knowledge in mind, I was able to use Configuration Management to export the View and the Entity view display, pull the appropriate setting names from the Entity view display, and manually apply them to the View YAML and reimport.  It's imperfect, but knowing that this should be possible was a great help in finding a workaround.